# Rails Polymorphic association with form collection_select without nesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I have the following models in my app

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :articles
has_many :tour_companies
has_many :accomodations
end

class Articles < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :bloggable, :polymorphic => true
end

class TourCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :articles, :as => :bloggable
end

class Accommodation < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :articles, :as => :bloggable
end
```

Now my problem is i want a logged in user to be able to write an article and use a form collection_select to select which one of his / her tour companies or accommodations the article should be associated with, how do i do it in rails 4? how do i select bloggable type and id from form collection select? I don't want nested resource

Answer (score 14):

Since Rails 4.2, this can be handled via [rails/globalid](https://github.com/rails/globalid). This newer option is used by Rails' ActiveJob. It makes the parsing and lookup very simple to setup.

First, check your `Gemfile.lock` for `globalid`. For Rails 5, it is included.

The magic all happens in the model...

Article Model:

```
# Use :to_global_id to populate the form
def bloggable_gid
  bloggable&.to_global_id
end

# Set the :bloggable from a Global ID (handles the form submission)
def bloggable_gid=(gid)
  self.bloggable = GlobalID::Locator.locate gid
end
```

To get a feel for what this does, open up a `rails console`. Play around with `gid = TourCompany.first.to_global_id` and `GlobalID::Locator.locate gid`.

Now the rest of your code is stock Rails stuff...

Articles Controller:

```
# consider building the collection in the controller.
# For Rails 5, this would be a `before_action`.
def set_bloggables
  @bloggables = TourCompany.all + Accomodation.all
end

# permit :bloggable_gid if you're using strong parameters...
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:bloggable_gid)
end
```

Articles Form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:bloggable_gid, @bloggables, :to_global_id, :to_s) %>
```

For more of a walk-through, [Simple Polymorphic Selects with Global IDs](https://www.railsagency.com/blog/2016/10/14/simple-polymorphic-selects-with-global-ids/) blog post is helpful.

Comment: great answer, I had to go lookup the try shorthand `&`. What a great trick!

Comment: Here in 2020 (and w/Rails 6) this is definitely the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

so i managed to finally do it. Here's how i did it
in the views/articles/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
<% bloggable_collection = TourCompany.all.map{|x| [x.title, "TourCompany:#{x.id}"]} +
                          Accomodation.all.map{|x| [x.title, "Accomodation:#{x.id}]}
%>
<p>Select one of your listing this article is associated with</p>
<%= f.select(:bloggable, bloggable_collection,:selected =>"#{f.object.bloggable_type}:#  {f.object.bloggable_id}" ) %>
</div>
```

Then in the Articles Controller

```
#use regular expression to match the submitted values
def create
bloggable_params = params[:article][:bloggable].match(/^(?<type>\w+):(?<id>\d+)$/)
params[:article].delete(:bloggable)

@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
@article.bloggable_id         =  bloggable_params[:id]
@article.bloggable_type       =  bloggable_params[:type]
if @article.save
  redirect_to admin_root_url, :notice => "Successfully created article"
else
  render 'new', :alert => "There was an error"
end
end
```

And it should work!